# Where can I find a Korean-English phrasebook in the form of laminated cards?

Tags: south-korea, language-barrier, communication, medical-tourism

Soon, I'm hoping to travel to South Korea to get voice surgery. I remember hearing of these laminated cards that you could use to point to a phrase or something in order to help communicate. Do you know what these are called? (Perhaps phrase card, but since NOTHING is coming up when I look for Korean phrase cards, I'm thinking it might be called something else). It might look something like this (but include a bit more information):

[image: A picture of a page including phrases in English and Korean. On this particular page, it is a picture of phrases to use at restaurants and at the airport]

Comment: Something like this? https://www.sprachriegel.de/shop/korea-riegel/ Unfortunately I can't find a Korean-English version (only Korea-German one) for this. The Chinese version looks fine to me but I never used it so I can't comment on how effective it is.

Comment: Have you considered Google Translate on a mobile phone as an alternative?  In addition to being a dynamic phrase book you can show people, it can translate speech in real time and in both directions.

Comment: Hi @lambshaanxy, yeah, I have considered it but the problem is my cellular carrier sucks with international coverage.

Comment: @VeroniqueBellamy Google Translate can work fully offline, just download the Korean pack before you go.

Answer (score 1):

Not cards, but I have a copy of *[This, Please](https://www.worldcat.org/title/this-please/oclc/751500737)*, which lets you point to a picture of the thing or activity you are interested in.  To go with that, you could perhaps make a card with translations of

```
Want
Don’t want
Where
How
I am unable to speak
Etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used a picture dictionary when I first visited Japan.  It worked out pretty well, and it was divided into categories so it was easy to find the item/word you wanted.

They have a Korean one:
ISBN-10: 0804849323
ISBN-13: 978-0804849326
UNSPSC Code: 55101500